# Как создать втеку именно для пользователя в discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

```
await ctx.author.add_roles(donate_role)
        # Create a thread with the name "принято ✅" and the initial message as "message"
        thread = await ctx.channel.create_thread(
            name="принято ✅",
            type=ChannelType.public_thread
        )
        await thread.send(f"Вам выдана <@&1189799283055132723>")
```